# jaxb java class to multiple xml mappings

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a couple of java classes that I want to convert to xml using jaxb. (I have no need to generate the classes based on the schema) I need to be able to map the class to different xml formats so I do not want to use annotations. From what I've seen my best option seems to be to use external xml bindings. So I wanted to know:

1) I am using eclipse. I am new to JAXB and I would like to know how to integrate external bindings using eclipse?

2) What other options other than external xml bindings are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you best option is to use MOXy XML bindings:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/runtime003.htm

This allows you to define XML<->Java mappings in form of XML files instead of annotations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="example">

    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Customer">
            <xml-root-element name="customer-info" />
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-attribute java-attribute="custId" name="customer-id" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="picture" name="picture-hex">
                    <xml-schema-type name="hexBinary" />
                    <xml-java-type-adapter
                        value="example.adapters.MyHexConverter" />
                </xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>

</xml-bindings>
```

You can use this file via `JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE` property:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, iStream);

JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { Customer.class }, properties);
```

So if you want several different mappings for the same class, just write several XML bindings and create your `JAXBContext` with corresponding files. I think this is the best options right now, with MOXy

With pure JAXB RI you can write an own annotations reader. I did this once with Annox:

- http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/JAXB+User+Guide

Another option was JBoss JAXBIntroductions, also based on a custom annotations reader:

- https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JAXBIntroductions

But I'm not sure this is live anymore.

Since you want multiple mappings, you'll have to write them (all but one) manually. You can generate one set of mappings as annotations, but further mappings will have to be written manually. Or, let's say, I'm not aware of a plugin or tool which would generate, for instance, MOXy XML bindings. Wouldn't be a big problem to write one though.

You may also take a completely different approach. Instead of mapping one central model with different mappings/format, you can have map a separate package of DTOs onto these formats. And then convert between your DTOs and the central model. Something like

```
XML(1) <-> DTO(1)|<-\
XML(2) <-> DTO(2)|<--*->Model
XML(3) <-> DTO(3)|<-/
```

Thus you'll have clean DTOs per exchange format (which you can generate out of schemas) and a single central business model (to rule them all). You'll have to convert between DTOs and the Model, this can be handled with a tool like Dozer.

If this is a better approach or not depends on how complex your formats are and how different they are fron one another.

Concerning your questions:

1) There's nothing special about Eclipse, just add MOXy as dependency and follow the docs.
2) I've described a few options above.

Comment: Yes, from when I previously looked at JBoss, it seemed outdated and useful during the time JAXB didn't support external bindings. I tried the first approach with MOXy. However I ran into some trouble where it doesn't seem to take the binding file into consideration. I posted my question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112876/jaxb-moxy-external-bindings-file-not-being-read). Appreciate it if you could help out.

Answer (score 0):

1. See "Passing Customization Files to the JAXB Binding Compiler" here:
   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/custom.html

You could write a script to integrate into Eclipse. Or you could use a Maven or Ant task.

2. Your only options are annotations or XML bindings.

Comment: A bindings file is passed to the JAXB XML Schema compiler xjc, and this is definitely something OP cannot do since he doesn't start from an XML Schema.

Comment: @laune Sorry, you're wrong. In MOXy there are "XML bindings" which is basically a substitute for annotations in XML form: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/runtime003.htm

Comment: @lexicore Will have to look into that, but this answer mentions the JAXB compiler, and this was ruled out by OP. So your comment should have been directed to my comment to the question (which I have deleted). I uphold my comment to this answer which does not address OPs problem.

Comment: Where does the OP rule out xjc or schema files? He said he wanted to use different formats, and he can do that with multiple schema files. What am I missing?