# JAXB MOXy external bindings file not being read

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to use external bindings so that I can have multiple xml configurations for the same java classes without using annotations in the code. The problem is my program does not seem to use the external bindings file that I use and instead just does default unmarshalling/marshalling.

I have the following classes:

Customer.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="customer") 
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Address address;
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

//getters and setters
```

Address.java

```
public class Address {

    private String street;
    //getters and setters
}
```

PhoneNumber.java

```
public class PhoneNumber {

    private String type;
    private String number;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Demo.java

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream iStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("src/blog/bindingfile/binding.xml");
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, iStream);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Customer.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/blog/bindingfile/input.xml");
        Customer customer = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, Customer.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
  }
```

I also tried an alternative version of Demo.java

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); 
        InputStream iStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("src/blog/bindingfile/binding.xml");
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, iStream);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Customer.class} , properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("src/blog/bindingfile/input.xml"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out); 
}
```

My Binding.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="blog.bindingfile">
    <xml-schema
        namespace="http://www.example.com/customer"
        element-form-default="QUALIFIED"/>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Customer">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <xml-type prop-order="firstName lastName address phoneNumbers"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="firstName" name="first-name"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="lastName" name="last-name"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="phoneNumbers" name="phone-number"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="PhoneNumber">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-attribute java-attribute="type"/>
                <xml-value java-attribute="number"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

And the input.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
    <first-name>Jane</first-name>
    <last-name>Doe</last-name>
    <address>
        <street>123 A Street</street>
    </address>
    <phone-number type="work">555-1111</phone-number>
    <phone-number type="cell">555-2222</phone-number>
</customer>
```

Whatever Demo.java I use the output I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
   <address>
      <street>123 A Street</street>
   </address>
</customer>
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. I noticed that no matter what I pass in as the binding.xml (even if the file doesn't exist) it doesn't complain.

Comment: Make sure you really use MOXy as implementation. And try removing all of the annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line:

```
InputStream iStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("src/blog/bindingfile/binding.xml");
```

iStream was null. Because the program couldn't find the file. However it will not throw any exceptions.

Then this null InputStream was passed into

```
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, iStream);
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Customer.class} , properties)
```

Again no exceptions are thrown, therefore the unmarshaller/marshaller does the unmarshalling/marshalling using the default rules and so we get the xml output shown in the question.

The file error was fixed by adding a new folder (resources) at the src folder level and then moving the binding.xml file there. Then the path was resources/binding.xml. Even using the full path did not work for me