# Generate Different types of XMl with same class using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have one class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="pickup")
public class PickUp 
{
    @XmlAttribute(name="contactName")
    public String contactName;
    @XmlAttribute(name="phoneNumber")
    public String phoneNumber;
    @XmlAttribute(name="pickupDate")
    public String pickupDate;
    @XmlAttribute(name="pickupTime")
    public String pickupTime;
    @XmlAttribute(name="closingTime")
    public String closingTime;
    @XmlAttribute(name="location")
    public String location;
}
```

This will generate XMl like this:

```
<Pickup contactName="Test Name" phoneNumber="888-888-8888" pickupDate="2009-08-03" pickupTime="16:30" closingTime="17:45" location="Front Door"/>
```

This is working perfect, but with same code  i also want to generate Xml like below:

```
<Pickup>
        <contactName>Test Name</contactName>
        <phoneNumber>888-888-8888</phoneNumber>
        <pickupDate>2009-08-03</pickupDate>
        <pickupTime>16:30</pickupTime>
        <closingTime>17:45</closingTime>
        <location>Front Door</location>
</Pickup>
```

I can do this by creating another class with `@xmlElement` but i want to use same class for this.
Please help me.

Comment: Please add reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33096124/1976843 answer that can help you.

If you want to keep using jaxb you will need to write your own AnnotationReader

Answer (score -1):

Your are using tags for XML attributes. Use `@XmlElement` tags to generate the XML in your required format you should give the tags as

```
@XmlElement  
public String getContactName() {  
    return contactName;  
}  
public void setcontactName(String name) {  
    this.contactName= name;  
}  
@XmlElement  
public String getphoneNumber() {  
    return phoneNumber;  
}  
public void setphoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {  
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;  
}
```

No need to create a new class. You can do changes in your original class for xml element.

Comment: Add a reason for downvoting. It helps to improve.

Comment: he says that he know how to change it to generate element. But he want to use same class to generate two different outputs.