# Options to map two different xml schema to one common Java object model

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am building an integration between two different web services.  Web Service A provides data in the form of:

```
<response>
<result>
<sys_title>some title</sys_title>
.....  //other xml elements
<sys_id>1234</sys_id>
</result>
...// repeating result elements
</response>
```

Web Service B stores data in this format:

```
<return>
<item>
<title>some title</title>
.....  //other xml elements
<id>1234</id>
</item>
...// repeating item elements
</return>
```

I know how to use JAXB to map the xml contents of each web service into a separate POJO class.
So, I end up with

```
ClassA { 
@XmlElement(name="sys_title")
String title;
@XmlElement(name=sys_id")
String id;
}

ClassB {
@XmlElement(name="title")
String title;
@XmlElement(name="id")
String id;
}
```

Since the data of interest to my integration is common, ie sys_title = title and sys_id = id, if is possible to use JAXB or some other solutions to define one common mapping?  Something along this line (obviously what I am writing is not supported)

```
CommonClass {
@XmlElement(name="sys_title")
@XmlElement(name="title")
String title;

@XmlElement(name="sys_id")
@XmlElement(name="id")
String id;
```

Basically, I am trying to avoid a mess of POJO classes to support web services A, web services B and the common model that I am working with.  Example function, find objects in application A expose via web service A that does not exist in web service B and create those objects in application B.

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091678/jaxb-java-class-to-multiple-xml-mappings

Comment: I had done a search first for prior questions before constructing my own.  The suggestion article was found in the search.  My  opinion after reviewing the article is that it is not really applicable.  Firstly, the solution there is to use Moxy/XML to generate multiple schemas from the common model.  In my case, I am constrained by the schema given by the web services so I cannot re-define teh schemas.  Secondly, I am trying to unmarshal the data from the web services to POJO classes.  Unless I mis-understood the article,, I could not use the information given.

Comment: I read another article from DZone about Moxy/XML and have gained better understanding of the article  stackoverflow.com/questions/33091678/.

Comment: I think you can close my question as duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jaxb java class to multiple xml mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091678/jaxb-java-class-to-multiple-xml-mappings)

Comment: Best of luck, I marked it as duplicate :)